# Refused to load image because it violates content security policy - html

Tags: html, content-security-policy

Here is a [website](https://CurieDoc.com) that I am working on, could someone please suggest why I get the error (violates content security policy) when I try to open https://CurieDoc.com/blog . I am using the path `/blog` to serve blog posts using [Hexo Blog](https://hexo.io)

Here is the error that I get:

> Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src'
>   was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

CSP Related headers that are being set:

```
// security headers
res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'")
res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')

// standard headers
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body, 'utf8'))
```

I have gone through several similar questions on this issue, but I was unable to find an answer to fix it. Any help/ guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Index.html page that I am trying to serve

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="generator" content="Curie Doc Blog">
    <title>Curie Doc Blog</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Curie Doc">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Indian doctor,Curie Doc,See a doctor now,Doctor Video Calls,Family Physician,">

    <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Website","@id":"https://CurieDoc.com/blog","author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Curie Doc","sameAs":[]},"name":"Curie Doc Blog","description":"See a doctor in minutes","url":"https://CurieDoc.com/blog","keywords":"Indian doctor, Curie Doc, See a doctor now, Doctor Video Calls, Family Physician"}</script>
    <meta name="description" content="See a doctor in minutes">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Indian doctor,Curie Doc,See a doctor now,Doctor Video Calls,Family Physician">
    <meta property="og:type" content="blog">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Curie Doc Blog">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://CurieDoc.com/blog/index.html">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Curie Doc Blog">
    <meta property="og:description" content="See a doctor in minutes">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Curie Doc Blog">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="See a doctor in minutes">

    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/blog/assets/css/style-gy2xr05rypagoa888viupqx1yk1agqb0hgbyket9uw1g2iljopyupsuh9nej.min.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->

</head>

<body>
    <div id="blog">
        <!-- Define author's picture -->

        <header id="header" data-behavior="1">
            <i id="btn-open-sidebar" class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
            <div class="header-title">
                <a class="header-title-link" href="/blog/ ">Curie Doc Blog</a>
            </div>

            <a class="header-right-picture " href="#about">

            </a>

        </header>

        <!-- Define author's picture -->

        <nav id="sidebar" data-behavior="1">
            <div class="sidebar-container">

                <ul class="sidebar-buttons">

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="/blog/ " title="Home">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="/blog/all-categories" title="Categories">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">Categories</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="/blog/all-tags" title="Tags">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">Tags</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="/blog/all-archives" title="Archives">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">Archives</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link open-algolia-search" href="#search" title="Search">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">Search</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="#about" title="About">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">About</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="sidebar-buttons">

                </ul>

                <ul class="sidebar-buttons">

                    <li class="sidebar-button">

                        <a class="sidebar-button-link " href="/blog/atom.xml" title="RSS">

                            <i class="sidebar-button-icon fa fa-lg fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sidebar-button-desc">RSS</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="main" data-behavior="1" class="
                            hasCoverMetaIn
                            ">
            <section class="postShorten-group main-content-wrap">

                <article class="postShorten postShorten--thumbnailimg-bottom">
                    <div class="postShorten-wrap">

                        <div class="postShorten-header">
                            <h1 class="postShorten-title">

                            <a class="link-unstyled" href="/blog/2018/06/18/hello-world/">
                                Hello World
                            </a>

                    </h1>
                            <div class="postShorten-meta">
                                <time datetime="2018-06-18T05:06:49+05:30">

                                    Jun 18, 2018

                                </time>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="postShorten-excerpt">
                            <p>Welcome to <a href="https://hexo.io/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hexo</a>! This is your very first post. Check <a href="https://hexo.io/docs/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">documentation</a> for more info. If you get any problems when using Hexo, you can find the answer in <a href="https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">troubleshooting</a> or you can ask me on <a href="https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GitHub</a>.</p>

                            <a href="/blog/2018/06/18/hello-world/" class="postShorten-excerpt_link link">
                                Continue reading
                            </a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </article>

                <article class="postShorten postShorten--thumbnailimg-bottom">
                    <div class="postShorten-wrap">

                        <div class="postShorten-header">
                            <h1 class="postShorten-title">

                            <a class="link-unstyled" href="/blog/2018/06/18/live-doctor-video-calls/">
                                Live Doctor Video Calls
                            </a>

                    </h1>
                            <div class="postShorten-meta">
                                <time datetime="2018-06-18T05:06:49+05:30">

                                    Jun 18, 2018

                                </time>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="postShorten-excerpt">
                            <p><img src="cover.png" alt="GitHub Logo"></p>
                            <p>Welcome to <a href="https://hexo.io/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hexo</a>! This is your very first post. Check <a href="https://hexo.io/docs/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">documentation</a> for more info. If you get any problems when using Hexo, you can find the answer in <a href="https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">troubleshooting</a> or you can ask me on <a href="https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GitHub</a>.</p>

                            <a href="/blog/2018/06/18/live-doctor-video-calls/" class="postShorten-excerpt_link link">
                                Continue reading
                            </a>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </article>

                <div class="pagination-bar">
                    <ul class="pagination">

                        <li class="pagination-number">page 1 of 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </section>

            <footer id="footer" class="main-content-wrap">
                <span class="copyrights">
            Copyrights &copy; 2018 Curie Doc. All Rights Reserved.
        </span>
            </footer>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="about">
        <div id="about-card">
            <div id="about-btn-close">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            </div>

            <h4 id="about-card-name">Curie Doc</h4>

            <div id="about-card-bio">
                <p>author.bio</p>
            </div>

            <div id="about-card-job">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                <br/>
                <p>author.job</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cover" style="background-image:url('/blog/assets/images/cover.jpg');"></div>
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/blog/assets/js/script-9xzvirgnfjjb76snlhrkwgttvljfm5b6mipdhr9evwsyiebdyoremsphbrbu.min.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We're not going to debug your live website for you. Please put all the relevant information needed to diagnose the issue into your question

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I thought I had added all the info I had, Please suggest any info that I missed.

Comment: Give us the URL of the page, the relevant HTML snippet, and possibly any CSP-related HTTP headers that are being set.

Comment: @deceze I've added html page that I am trying to serve as well, I should had added these before, thank you for pointing out.